# Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: buffer underrun

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, mono, mod-mono

I have a very strange problem.

We implemented a Soap API to talk to a third party. The API sort of works. There is an `IsAlive` method which checks if the third party service is alive.

Our application is hosted on an `Ubuntu 14.04` server under `Apache` with `Mod-Mono` (`Mono`).

We call this API when we load a particular page. It works up to a point then we get an error. I.E. You can make a request to the `IsAlive` xxx (It's random) amount of times and it works, then next time you try and do it the following exception gets thrown:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: buffer underrun


  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: buffer underrun
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream+<SetHeadersAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 (IAsyncResult r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessException (System.Exception e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ASP.somepage_aspx.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: buffer underrun
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The API at this point does not work anymore. Even if we refresh the page and make another call. We try to re-request 2-3 times then we get another error.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessException (System.Exception e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ASP.somepage_aspx.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The only way to make the API work again is if we restart the Ubuntu Server.

Here is a snippet of how we send the request.

```
public string TestSiteStatus()
{
    getSiteStatus site = new getSiteStatus();
    site.site = "XXX";
    string res = "";
    using (SiteServiceImplService service = new SiteServiceImplService())
    {
        res = service.getSiteStatus(site);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Is there a problem with my implementation or is this a Mono framework issue?

I have tried the instructions on this page: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/ but no success. When I run thetest, it passes the first and sometimes the second time but fails after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a certificate issue with our third party. They updated their certificates, we added them to our stores, and it worked.

Our the API SSL cert was vulnerable to a LogJam attack. The ciphering of the certificate caused problems with our server.

This [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/) helped us test and find the problem.